# If/Else Statement does not run the else

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/messedUP90/pm2e8dyb/2/):

I am struggling with my If/Else statement. I cannot get the else part of the statement to run. I assume it is something with the ordering... but nothing I try has been helping.

What I want to happen: click the pink button and the small pink appears. click the green button the little green box appears and the pink disappears.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="pport01"></div>
<div id="pport02"></div>
<div class="p01"></div>
<div class="p02"></div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#pport01{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: pink;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#pport02{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.p01{
    position:relative;
    display: none;
    width: 10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color: pink;
    display: none;

}

.p02{
    position:relative;
    display:none;
    width: 10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here is the JS:

```
var active01 = false;
var active02 = false;

$('#pport01').click(function(){
    active02= false;
    active01 = true;
    if(active01){
        console.log(active01 + "port1 true");
        $('.p01').fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
        console.log(active01 + "port1 false");
        $('.p02').fadeOut("slow");
    }
});

$('#pport02').click(function(){
    active01 = false;
    active02 = true;
    if(active02){
        console.log(active02 + "port2 true");
        $('.p02').fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
        console.log(active02 + "port2 false");
        $('.p02').fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
```

It turns out I did not want the if/else statement there. Thank you everyone for your help!
[It works now!](https://jsfiddle.net/messedUP90/yfvkjwLh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code:

```
$('#pport01').click(function(){
    active02= false;

// active01 is set to true before the IF

    active01 = true;
    if(active01){
        console.log(active01 + "port1 true");
        $('.p01').fadeIn("slow");
    }else{
        console.log(active01 + "port1 false");
        $('.p02').fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
```

active01 will always be true when the `if` is resolved, so the else will never be evaluated.  You should rethink what you intend to achieve.

Maybe you don't need the if:

```
$('#pport01').click(function(){
        $('.p01').fadeIn("slow");
        $('.p02').fadeOut("slow");
});

$('#pport02').click(function(){
        $('.p02').fadeIn("slow");
        $('.p01').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: yeah that makes sense! but i cannot seem to think of a solution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seem that you want to alternate fadeing in and out .p01 and .p02 when you click on the pport buttons (or whatever they are). In that case try the second code

Comment: this was a very simplified example. in my actual code I will have 10 buttons. when one is clicked it deactivates the others. also when one is clicked it will dim 50%. when the buttons are deactivated they will dim 25% on hover. when the buttons are activated they will dim to 75% on hover.

Comment: you know what... that is actually what I want. I do not want an if/else statement there. Thank you for helping me wrap my head around it! This is what I wanted to do. https://jsfiddle.net/messedUP90/yfvkjwLh/

Answer (score 2):

As you set the **boolean** `active01` and `active02` to true respectively right before the if/else condition, you will never enter the else loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no jquery expert, but to my uneducated eye the problem is with your value assignment immediately before the `if` statement:

```
active01 = true;
if(active01){...
```

when you've explicitly set the `active01` flag to true, the `if` will always be satisfied, so the `else` will never be run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#pport01').click(function(){
if(active01){
    console.log(active01 + "port1 true");
    $('.p01').fadeIn("slow");
}else{
    console.log(active01 + "port1 false");
    $('.p02').fadeOut("slow");
}
active02= false;
active01 = true;
}
```

The problem is that you assign values for active01 and active02 before IF so it's normal for active01 to be always true and the first IF statement to be always executed
Same thing for the second function, assign active01 and active02 after IF/ELSE

Answer (score 1):

For this block, your else statement won't run because the boolean active02 is true declared to be true at the beginning of the function.

The same thing for your first block. Only that you've reversed the order of active01 and active02.

```
$('#pport02').click(function(){
active01 = false;
active02 = true;
if(active02){
    console.log(active02 + "port2 true");
    $('.p02').fadeIn("slow");
}else{
    console.log(active02 + "port2 false");
    $('.p02').fadeOut("slow");
}
```

});

If you are trying to toggle between active01 and active02 being true, run your if / else statement first before reassigning your flags.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
active01 === true ? $('.p01').fadeIn("slow") :  $('.p02').fadeOut("slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your are trying to do this:

```
$('#pport01').click(function(){
  $('.p01').fadeIn("slow");
  $('.p02').fadeOut("slow");

});

$('#pport02').click(function(){
   $('.p02').fadeIn("slow");
   $('.p01').fadeOut("slow");

});
```